# CSS div overlay and jQuery

Tags: jquery, css, overlay

This is more or less a [CSS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cascading_Style_Sheets) question but I am using it with [jQuery](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JQuery). OK, so basically what I have is this:

```
<div
  style="overflow: hidden; width: 1000px; height: 450px; background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0); position: relative;"
  id="wrapper">
    <div
      style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); opacity: 0.9; top: 0pt; left: 0pt; width: 1000px; height: 450px; position: absolute; z-index: 500;"
      id="mask"></div>
    <div
      class="ui-draggable"
      style="margin: 60px auto auto; position: relative; width: 1550px; height: 340px;"
      id="test">
        <div style="float: left; margin-left: 10px; width: 100px; position: relative;" class="row">
            <div
              style="width: 100px; height: 100px; margin-top: 10px; position: relative;"
             ><img
                 style="width: 100px; height: 100px; position: relative;"
                 class="img"
                 src="/images/Chrysanthemum.jpg"></div>
            <div
              style="width: 100px; height: 100px; margin-top: 10px; position: relative;"
            ><img
                 style="width: 100px; height: 100px; position: relative;"
                 class="img"
                 src="/images/Desert.jpg"></div>
            <div
              style="width: 100px; height: 100px; margin-top: 10px; position: relative;"
            ><img
                style="width: 100px; height: 100px; position: relative;"
                class="img"
                src="/images/Hydrangeas.jpg"></div>
        </div>
        <div style="float: left; margin-left: 10px; width: 100px; position: relative;" class="row">
            <div
               style="width: 100px; height: 100px; margin-top: 10px; position: relative;"
            ><img
                style="width: 100px; height: 100px; position: relative;"
                class="img"
                src="/images/Jellyfish.jpg"></div>
            <div
              style="width: 100px; height: 100px; margin-top: 10px; position: relative;"
            ><img
                style="width: 100px; height: 100px; position: relative;"
                class="img"
                src="/images/Koala.jpg"></div>
            <div
               style="width: 100px; height: 100px; margin-top: 10px; position: relative;"
            ><img
                style="width: 100px; height: 100px; position: relative;"
                class="img"
                src="/images/Lighthouse.jpg"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div
   style="position: absolute; left: 978px; top: 223px; color: rgb(255, 255, 255);"
   id="next-btn">Next</div>
<div
   style="position: absolute; left: 8px; top: 223px; color: rgb(255, 255, 255);"
   id="prev-btn">Prev</div>
```

What I am doing with the mask div is trying to get it to overlay the whole wrapper. So I set its width and height to the height of the wrapper. This works fine in Firefox, Chrome and Safari.

However, in Internet Explorer it is not working. How can I make this overlay?

I tried setting the position to absolute which worked fine except one thing. There is something that is going on top of this mask. Its position is relative. I set the one on top to a z-index of 1000 and the mask to 500. However it seems there is a bug in Internet Explorer that automatically makes an absolute div be on top of everything.

Comment: Include the css for those elements in the question, just paste it in, and/or include a link to where you have this online.

Comment: ngreenwood6, why ought anybody give you an answer if you don't award them for their efforts? I'm not being rude or short with you, I'm simply inviting you to better your experience and the experience of others by fully participating in StackOverflow.

Comment: updated code with output of generated source. this is pretty much going to be a photo gallery but another problem I found is that when I setup a click event for the images. But when the images are clicked in ff its fine but in ie the other images below it move down. I HATE IE. I have to leave the images as relative because I am moving it relatively due to its offset on the page. Absolute screws it up.

Comment: ngreenwood6, be careful who you are rude to also :) Here's a list of people that can help you on this question: http://stackoverflow.com/badges/116/css Not very long, but 50% of the names should look familiar :)

Comment: once again if your not going to contribute to my question dont reply

Comment: wow jonathon you should feel special that you know css. know if only you knew what I knew how to do like php, javascript, jquery, c++, c#, java, flash lol

Comment: being rude to people who are trying to help you is not an effective way to get answers to your questions. Just FYI.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> however it seems there is a bug in ie that automatically makes an absolute div be on top of everything.

No. The problem is that Internet Explorer [doesn't support the CSS3 opacity tag](http://www.webdeveloper.com/forum/showthread.php?t=177952). You'll have to add the following style to your mask DIV to make it work in IE too:

```
filter: alpha(opacity=90);
```

Also read [here](http://www.ruzee.com/blog/2006/04/support-for-opacity-in-modern-browser/) and [here](http://www.stevenyork.com/tutorial/pure_css_opacity_and_how_to_have_opaque_children) for more tips on how to implement opacity correctly.

On a sidenote, you should use inline styles less often. It makes your code messy and hard to debug.

Answer (score 0):

Which version of IE? at any rate you can overlay your absolute object with another absolute object, then put the relative content inside that.

Comment: I am using ie8. I cant use another absolute object because the object I am using is relative and must stay that way. I am updating the original code right now.